# How to capture Print output

Tags: printing, output

How can I capture output from Print from a function which does not leave the printed object as its final output, (and which I do not wish to edit)? E.g.

```
Module[{},
 Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]];
 a = 123]
```

I would like to use something like a temporary setting for `$PrePrint` or `$Post`, rather than use cell selection (`SelectionMove`, `NotebookRead`).

The aim is somehow to intercept the `Print` output -- the plot object -- and set it to a variable, (without altering the module).

This attempt did not work:-

[image]

Comment: I probably don't understand the problem but doesn't `Print[Sow@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]` and `// Reap` at the end captures Print output?

Comment: Do you want the `123` being stored, the plot, or both?

Comment: I just want to pick up the plot object. The problem is the module should not be edited, otherwise it would be simple to set a variable inside the `Print` command.

Comment: So you want something like `$PrePrint` or `$Post` which would also capture the output of `Plot[Sin[x],{x,-5,5}];`?

Comment: @acl - Yes, as I have done below using `$Output`. But setting a variable with `$PrePrint` could be neater.

Comment: Have you considered using `CellPrint[]` instead?

Comment: @J.M. - no, I can't see how `CellPrint` could be used.  But the idea is not to alter the module.

Comment: If you need to collect the printed output and it's lready generated, you may try my answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38220/193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can temporarily redefine `Print`, like so:

```
fun[] := Module[{}, Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]];
  a = 123]

list = {};
Block[{Print = AppendTo[list, {##}] &}, fun[]]
```

Now `list` contains everything that was printed.  (Of course in a practical application you'd probably want to do something smarter than an inefficient periodic `AppendTo`)

If you still want to print the expressions while simultaneously saving them, use the [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) to redefine `Print`.

Answer (score 9):

I have found one solution, using a temporary file:-

```
streams = AppendTo[$Output, OpenWrite[]];

Module[{},
  Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]];
  a = 123];

Close@Last@streams;
$Output = Most@streams;
printoutput = ReadList@First@Last@streams
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Anyway to  modify it so that the printed text is not outputted at all, but still captured to `printoutput`?

Comment: @Kvothe Yes, use `Block` as per Szabolcs' answer. (Writes to `list`.)

Comment: Thanks. I wrongly assumed that the `Block` method would not work for my case since the printed output is printed in python during `ExternalEvaluate`. Upon testing it does actually work so apparently these statements still get printed in Mathematica by internally using `Print`.