# How to collect expressions from cells created by Print?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, expression-manipulation, cells

I have a notebook where evaluation of a certain cell produced hundreds of adjacent output cells using `Print`. I need to create a list containing all expressions from those output cells as elements, and assign the list to a variable **without re-running the evaluation**.

Could you suggest a way to automate this process to avoid manually copying all expressions?

Comment: See this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22584/363

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following  seems to work, however I think it's not general enough:

At a clean nb, enter:

```
For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[{i, {33, i}}]]
For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 20]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then retrieve the `Print[ ]` output as:

```
c = Cases[NotebookRead /@ Cells[GeneratedCell -> True], Cell[___, "Print", ___]];
ToExpression /@ Cases[c, BoxData[__], {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Block[{Print = Sow},
  Do[Print[i], {i, 1, 1000}] // Reap
]
```

Comment: In my case, re-running of the evaluation would take longer that manual copying of expressions from existing cells.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't read "(without re-running the evaluation)".

Answer (score 1):

Make each result the argument of a pure function; e.g., `(Sow[#]; Print[#])&[whatever]`, with all the functions inside a `Reap`. That also lets you format the printed output in a way that might be easier for a person to read but more awkward to read back into Mma.

Comment: Please see the OP's comment under @RiemannZeta answer. The nb has already been calculated. It's too late to change the code.